# Python - Upload or Download a picture from Online Database

Tags: python, database, file-upload, upload, kivy

I'm working on Python with an Kivy app that **taking pictures of people, saving their names** on a .db file and saving their photos on a folder in my PC.

I want to upload their names and photos on a **online database** with Python and sometimes I want to connect the database via outside network on anywhere and download pictures.

Is there any platform to create this database?

Comment: you can create a database on the cloud, and using rest api you can connect to the database and upload and retrieve the data from the database. you can access it from any network

Comment: on which cloud ? I want to know the simplest one. can Google Firebase do it ?

Comment: you have to create this on the web server , this  webserver is connected with the database. using rest api you connect with this webserver through your app and do the operation you want to do. google firebase can do this.

Comment: Yes, you should be able to do it with Google Firebase. You should use the Firebase real-time database to store smaller bits of info, like their names, and then Firebase Storage most likely to hold your images since they're larger. Using python, you'd need to work with these via their REST api